# How to display image

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to display images from the CIFAR-10 TensorFlow tutorial. The images become transformed so that the values  read are floats more less between -1 and 3. I'm not show what kind of transformation has been applied. How can I display them to see the original content?

Here is what the part of the image output looks like:

```
 array([[ 1.24836731,  0.04940184, -1.49835348],\n       [ 1.117571  ,    0.02760247, -1.56375158],\n       [ 1.24836731,  0.18019807, -1.41115606],\n       [ 1.18296909,  0.09300058, -1.47655416],\n       [ 1.13937044,  0.02760247, -1.54195225],\n       [ 1.13937044,  0.09300058, -1.52015293],\n
```

...

```
np.max(image)
2.9269187

np.min(image)
-1.759946
```

This is the link to the tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/

Edit:

Rescaling does not seem to work for me:

[image]

Comment: You can improve your question by providing the link for the TensorFlow tutorial which you have mentioned above. You can also post the code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try scaling the image to be between 0 and 255? Subtract the min and divide by its new max.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways to do this, for the greyscale MNIST images:

```
tmp = mnist.train.images[0]
tmp = tmp.reshape((28,28))

plt.imshow(tmp, cmap = cm.Greys)
plt.show()
```

Or, for CIFAR-10 images:
Code below taken from [this](https://houxianxu.github.io/implementation/SoftmaxRegression.html) tutorial

```
def visualize_sample(X_train, y_train, classes, samples_per_class=7):
"""visualize some samples in the training datasets """
num_classes = len(classes)
for y, cls in enumerate(classes):
    idxs = np.flatnonzero(y_train == y) # get all the indexes of cls
    idxs = np.random.choice(idxs, samples_per_class, replace=False)
    for i, idx in enumerate(idxs): # plot the image one by one
        plt_idx = i * num_classes + y + 1 # i*num_classes and y+1 determine the row and column respectively
        plt.subplot(samples_per_class, num_classes, plt_idx)
        plt.imshow(X_train[idx].astype('uint8'))
        plt.axis('off')
        if i == 0:
            plt.title(cls)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The thing is that while training the image training batch is created using multiple threads and `tf.train.batch`. Visualizng this train batch is the issue and I'm afraid I cannot apply this method here.